# Common compiler config in CMake

Tags: cmake

Assume I have C++ app A and C++ libs B and C. A uses B and C, C uses B.

They all are in separate Git repositories and have the same compiler config in their `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang")
  # using Clang
elseif ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
  # using GCC
  add_definitions("-Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-function -pedantic -pthread")
elseif ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Intel")
  # using Intel C++
elseif ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")
  # using Visual Studio C++
  add_compile_options("/Zc:__cplusplus")
  add_compile_options("/W4")
  add_definitions(-D_UNICODE)
  add_definitions(-MP)
endif()
```

What is the right way to move this to a separate script and share it between A, B and C?

Should it be a CMake module?

Comment: This is precisely what [toolchain files](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) were designed to solve.

Comment: @AlexReinking: Toolchain files are for explaining a platform to CMake, not for explaining a platform to the project itself. Setting flags like `-Wall` doesn't belong to the toolchain. Such settings could be moved into the separate CMake script(module), but not to a toolchain file.

Comment: If you want to be able to build libs `B` and `C` on their own and avoid duplication of the logic, you'll need to introduce a git submodule with a `.cmake` file containing this logic. If A is always part of the project, just apply the settings before you add the other repos via `add_subdirectory` and those settings should be applied to those subdirectories as well...